# Flutter how to unlock NFC tag with password to Rewrite data?

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I need to unlock NFC tag by password to Rewrite some data Then lock tag by password again.

Note => I know NFC Tools mobile app but I need to unlock (remove Password) tag programatly.

Note => I know password's tag but I need to unlock (remove Password) tag programatly.

Comment: Password protection is usually specific to the make/model of the Tag, so it is impossible to answer without knowing the make/model of your Tag, but all the details of the low level commands you will need to send to the Tag will be defined in the Tag's datasheet.

Comment: I know what kind of tag and I know password protection.

tag type: NXP MIFARE Ultralight - NTAG213

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have u found something then please help me.also share with us

Comment: I am using MifareUltralight NFCtag to set/reset password using NdefMessage

Answer (score 0):

So first off, how NFC is handled is different in iOS and Android and you would have to write specific parts of your code for each OS, but are very similar in that you send a command to the Tag and receive a response.

The Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63259021/2373819 gives a good breakdown for password protection for the ntag series of tags, even though this example is for iOS the command to send are the same (Note you will have to adjust the page addresses as this example is for the larger ntag 216 tag).

You don't have to remove the password from the Tag unless you want to change the password, you just need to authenticate with the current password then you can write data as normal while the Tag is still in range.

To access NFC in flutter you will need a package, there are many different ones available with different capabilities but a popular one seems to be https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager

As you only Tagged Android on this question then you will need to use the [NfcA transceive](https://pub.dev/documentation/nfc_manager/latest/platform_tags/NfcA/transceive.html) method to send the `authenticate` and then `write` commands to the Tag

The nfc_manager package has examples of how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But can you help me how to use This method (NfcA transceive) what data i will send it to be authenticated and then write.